# How can I enumerate D6-symmetric cellular automaton rules?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, dihedral-groups, cellular-automata

I'm experimenting with rules for a cellular automaton in a hexagonal grid. I am wondering how to enforce symmetry.

For example a cell can be either "alive" or "dead". Let's say a rule maps the state of 6 neighbours to the next state of the center. There are 2^6 possible rules (easy to enumerate).

But now I would like those rules to be symmetric. After some research I found that the dihedral group (D6) describes the symmetry I want. But I just remembered that group theory exists at all, so I'm a bit lost with my next question:

How can I enumerate all possible rules that are invariant to this symmetry? Is there a notation or concept to help with this?

I have done it manually and counted 13(*) possible inputs that are distinguishable if the rule is invariant to D6 transformations of its input. But how can I count them formally? What group-theory concept(s) should I study for this?

(*) Here are the 13 I've found (click to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: Check your work. I suspect there are 12, not 13.

Comment: I think I counted them right, I've added my sketch to maybe clarify what I've counted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are binary [bracelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)). That article invokes the [Pólya enumeration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem), but you can also derive the result using [Burnside’s lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), which is less general but slightly more accessible. To do so, you need to count the pairs $(S,C)$ of symmetry operations $S$ and configurations $C$ such that $S$ leaves $C$ invariant. This you can do by counting the [orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of each symmetry operation; each orbit can independently be assigned a colour to obtain an input that the operation leaves invariant, so $n$ orbits yield $2^n$ invariant configurations.

In your case, the identity has $6$ orbits, a rotation through $60°$ (of which there are $2$) has $1$ orbit, a rotation through $120°$ (of which there are $2$) has $2$ orbits, the rotation through $180°$ has $3$ orbits, a reflection in a line through two corners (of which there are $3$) has $4$ orbits, and a reflection in an edge bisector (of which there are $3$) has $3$ orbits. Thus, in total there are

$$
2^6+2\cdot2^1+2\cdot2^2+2^3+3\cdot2^4+3\cdot2^3 = 156
$$

pairs of symmetry operations and invariant configurations, so by Burnside’s lemma, as the group has $12$ elements, there are $\frac{156}{12}=13$ inequivalent configurations.